# Union resulting in duplicate rows - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, union

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
|  Order | Step | Step_Complete_Date |
|:------:|:----:|:------------------:|
| ABC454 |   1  |     12/21/2018     |
| ABC454 |   2  |     12/22/2018     |
| ABC454 |   3  |        NULL        |
| ABC454 |   4  |     12/23/2018     |
| ABC454 |   5  |     12/23/2018     |
| ABC433 |   1  |      1/1/2019      |
| ABC433 |   2  |      1/1/2019      |
| ABC433 |   3  |      1/2/2019      |
| ABC433 |   4  |      1/3/2019      |
| ABC433 |   5  |      1/7/2019      |
| ABC600 |   1  |      2/1/2019      |
| ABC600 |   2  |      2/7/2019      |
| ABC600 |   3  |      3/1/2019      |
| ABC600 |   4  |        NULL        |
| ABC600 |   5  |        NULL        |
| ABC800 |   1  |      5/1/2019      |
| ABC800 |   2  |      5/5/2019      |
| ABC800 |   3  |      5/5/2019      |
| ABC800 |   4  |      5/5/2019      |
| ABC800 |   5  |        NULL        |
| ABC999 |   1  |      7/1/2019      |
| ABC999 |   2  |      7/1/2019      |
| ABC999 |   3  |      7/1/2019      |
| ABC999 |   4  |      7/1/2019      |
| ABC999 |   5  |        NULL        |
```

I need to write SQL query to find any order where step 4 or step 5 has been completed (i.e., `Step_Completed_Date` is not null)

I tried the following:

```
WITH
  step4 AS
    (
       SELECT Order_No, Step_No, Step_Complete_Date AS Step_4_Complete_Date, NULL AS Step_5_Complete_Date
       FROM tblSteps
       WHERE Step_No = '4' AND Step_Complete_Date IS NOT NULL
     ),

   step5 AS
    (
       SELECT Order_No, Step_No, NULL AS Step_4_Complete_Date, Step_Complete_Date AS Step_5_Complete_Date
       FROM tblSteps
       WHERE Step_No = '5' AND Step_Complete_Date IS NOT NULL
     )

   SELECT * FROM Step4
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM Step5
```

but it results in:

```
| ORDER_NO | STEP_NO | STEP_4_COMPLETE_DATE | STEP_5_COMPLETE_DATE |
|:--------:|:-------:|:--------------------:|:--------------------:|
|  ABC433  |    4    |       1/3/2019       |        (null)        |
|  ABC433  |    5    |        (null)        |       1/7/2019       |
|  ABC454  |    4    |      12/23/2018      |        (null)        |
|  ABC454  |    5    |        (null)        |      12/23/2018      |
|  ABC800  |    4    |       5/5/2019       |        (null)        |
|  ABC999  |    4    |       7/1/2019       |        (null)        |
```

When ideally, it would look like:

```
| ORDER_NO | STEP_4_COMPLETE_DATE | STEP_5_COMPLETE_DATE |
|:--------:|:--------------------:|:--------------------:|
|  ABC433  |       1/3/2019       |       1/7/2019       |
|  ABC454  |      12/23/2018      |      12/23/2018      |
|  ABC800  |       5/5/2019       |        (null)        |
|  ABC999  |       7/1/2019       |        (null)        |
```

How can I change my SQL to create desired output? I have set up a [SQL FIDDLE here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f5ff/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would aggregate here and then use the `HAVING` clause to assert which orders are matching and which are not:

```
SELECT
    ORDER_NO,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Step = 4 THEN Step_Complete_Date END) AS STEP_4_COMPLETE_DATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Step = 5 THEN Step_Complete_Date END) AS STEP_5_COMPLETE_DATE
FROM tblSteps
GROUP BY
    ORDER_NO
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Step IN (4, 5) AND Step_Complete_Date IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using aggregation and group by

```
WITH
  step4 AS
    (
       SELECT Order_No, Step_No, Step_Complete_Date AS Step_4_Complete_Date, NULL AS Step_5_Complete_Date
       FROM tblSteps
       WHERE Step_No = '4' AND Step_Complete_Date IS NOT NULL
     ),

   step5 AS
    (
       SELECT Order_No, Step_No, NULL AS Step_4_Complete_Date, Step_Complete_Date AS Step_5_Complete_Date
       FROM tblSteps
       WHERE Step_No = '5' AND Step_Complete_Date IS NOT NULL
     )

   SELECT SELECT Order_No, ,max(Step_4_Complete_Date),max(Step_5_Complete_Date) FROM Step4 group by Order_No, 
   UNION
   SELECT SELECT Order_No ,max(Step_4_Complete_Date),max(Step_5_Complete_Date) FROM Step5 group by Order_No
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `GROUP BY` as following:

```
SELECT Order_No, '4' AS Step_No, 
MAX(CASE WHEN Step_No = 4 THEN Step_Complete_Date END) AS Step_4_Complete_Date, 
MAX(CASE WHEN Step_No = 5 THEN Step_Complete_Date END) AS Step_4_Complete_Date
FROM tblSteps
WHERE Step_No IN ('4','5') AND Step_Complete_Date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Order_No
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f5ff/5)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot function to make step 4 complete date and step 5 complete date as columns

```
select * from
(
select order_no , step_complete_date , step_no from tblSteps where step_no in (4,5)
)
pivot
(
  max(step_complete_date)
  for step_no in ( 4 as step_4_complete_dt , 5 as step_5_complete_dt)
)
where    nvl (step_4_complete_dt ,step_5_complete_dt ) is not null
```

the last where clause is to eliminate rows where the completion date of both 4 and 5 are null

Note, the step_no column will not appear here, and I am not clear on why you need the step no column of if it shows the completion date for both steps in a single row

Hope this solves your purpose

Answer (score 0):

A version of conditional aggregation

```
SELECT
    ORDER_NO,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Step = 4 THEN Step_Complete_Date END) AS STEP_4_COMPLETE_DATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Step = 5 THEN Step_Complete_Date END) AS STEP_5_COMPLETE_DATE
FROM tblSteps
WHERE Step IN (4, 5)
GROUP BY ORDER_NO
HAVING COUNT(Step_Complete_Date) > 0;
```